# Cordova geolocation.getCurrentPosition() stops working after it is called 3 times

Tags: cordova, gps, location

So I have an app that when QR code is scanned it will also get location of your device. The problem is I'm getting same coords most of the time. First scan and 2 after will be different but after that it is always same coords, sometimes i even get timeout. Maximum age is on 0 (not using cached coords), timeout on 5000 and High Accuracy is on TRUE. what could be the problem?

```
function scan() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, { maximumAge: 0, timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true });
}

function onSuccess(position) {
    window.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    window.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    console.log('GPS is ON');
    navigator.notification.alert("Success, lng: " + window.longitude + "lat: " + window.latitude,alertDismissed,"EAM");
}

 function onError() {
    navigator.notification.alert("Can't get your location, please scan asset again!",alertDismissed,"EAM");
    console.log('GPS is off');
    document.getElementById('button-change').disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: where do you test it, in emulation or on a real device? Could you paste your code for the geolocation, just to see if there is any hint to solve your problem.

Comment: On real device. I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem by using an older version of the plugin. In config.xml file i put 2.4.3 version and everything is working good.